# Extract Archived Log Files from RMAN Backupset

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, rman, backup, archive

I have an RMAN backup that is taken on 19th january with: **BACKUP DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG** command. Now I need to restore Archived logs from that backupset to some other OS directory. Is there any way to extract Archived Log files from that backup?

Comment: Finally, an intelligent question! I am beginning to despair for the quality of this site.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

```
RMAN > run  
{
    ALLOCATE CHANNEL d1 DEVICE TYPE disk;
    restore archivelog all;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use catalog, because a long time passed since January.

```
rman target / catalog rman_catalog_user@rman_catalog_db

RUN
{ 
  SET ARCHIVELOG DESTINATION TO '/oracle/temp_restore';
  RESTORE ARCHIVELOG FROM TIME = "to_date('2014-01-19 19:20:00','YYYY-DD-MM HH24:MI:SS')"  
                    UNTIL TIME = "to_date('2014-01-19 20:00:00','YYYY-DD-MM HH24:MI:SS')";
}
```